# cordova ios : cordova.exec() undefined is not a function

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, undefined

I'm developing an iOS app using cordova(1.9). I've some custom iOS plugins to make my app do some stuff. Now I'm facing a problem, sometime when I call :

```
cordova.exec(function(){},function(){},'MyPlugin','myMethod',['parameter']);
```

The app throws this exception :

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'cordova.exec(function(){},function(){},'WDMessageDispatcher','sendMessage',['showCategoriesList'])')
```

The Plugin was developed following the documentation and it works but not everytime. I don't really understand why. Someone else experienced the same error?

Comment: are you calling cordova.exec before the deviceReady() Event has fired?

Comment: Yes the problem is that I call cordova.exec before deviceReady() is fired (I'm an idiot). I just wondering if deviceReady is fired only once or more than once. Anyway if you answer to this question I'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: cool, glad I could help. I myself made the mistake too...and we´re by far not the only :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> cordova.exec

can be invoked after

> deviceReady()

has fired.

Comment: How did you implement the calling of cordova.exec after deviceReady()? The cordova.android.js & ..ios.js files cannot be modified.